# Copy document contents in google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to copy the content of a document into another, both stored in google drive, using Google Drive Api for Java. I'm able to upload or download documents but I don't know how *directly transfer* the content of a document into another one. I thought of something like that:

```
public void copyContent(String sourceId, String destinationId) {
   File sourceFile = service.files().get(sourceId).execute();
   AbstractInputStreamContent content = null; //sourceFile.getContent()??? :-(

   File destinationFile = service.files().get(destinationId).execute();
   service.files().update(destinationId, destinationFile, content).execute();
}
```

There's a way to get the file content as AbstractInputStreamContent? Or maybe it exists another approach to copy contents? I need a solution without exporting / uploading documents because I noticed some conversion problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `files.copy` method of the Drive API to create a copy of an existing document:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy

Comment: Hi Claudio, thank you very much for your answer. I was aware of the method copy() but it's going to create a new file with a new id. I want to maintain the old id ("destinationId" in my example) because my application is referring to it in many places. Maybe could I set the id of the new file created by copy() and delete the "destination file"?

Comment: You cannot set the id, so I guess you'll have to download the source file and update the destination one using its content.

Comment: Download a document means that I should export it using a supported format (for example .odt). Right? Then, when I'll upload the file it's going to be reconverted to a "google document". Unfortunately I've already had experience with this process and I noticed that there are some problems reconverting a file to a "google document" (For example colored table borders become black). Is it possible to download a document using directly the "google document" format: application/vnd.google-apps.document?

Comment: Ok, I'll write a copyContent() function using _Google Apps Script_, I'll _deploy it as web app_ and I'll call it from _Google Drive API_. Thanks anyway for the useful informations!